# Count number of observations used to calculate the mean in SAS

Tags: count, sas

I want to generate a new column n which will answer the question: How many levels was the mean calculated from? 1 or 2 or 3?

Is there a way to calculate N without converting the data from long to wide format? N should tell us the number of observations that were required to calculate the mean. Thank you.

My input dataset is:

````
   input entity $ level $ value mean; 
   datalines; 
        A   Level1  5.85    5.9
        A   Level2  5.95    5.9
        B   Level1  0.12    0.12
        B   Level2  0.12    0.12
        B   Level3  0.12    0.12
        C   Level1  0.8     0.8
        C   Level2  .       0.8
        D   Level1  .       0.23
        D   Level2  .       0.23
        D   Level3  0.23    0.23
        E   Level1  9.6     9.35
        E   Level2  9.1     9.35
        F   Level1  .       3.9
        F   Level2  3.9     3.9
;```
````

Comment: How did you calculate the MEAN?  Why not calculate N at the same time as you calculate MEAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it the same why you calculated the mean.

So if you use PROC SUMMARY then ask for the N statistic in addition to the MEAN statistic.

```
proc summary data=have ;
  by entity level ;
  var value;
  output out=means mean=mean n=n ;
run;
```

If you use PROC SQL then use the N() aggregate function in addition to the MEAN() aggregate function.  You could also use the COUNT() aggregate function.

```
 proc sql;
 create table want as 
   select entity,level,value,n(value) as n,mean(value) as mean
   from have
   group by entity,level
 ;
 quit;
```

Comment: Thank you @Tom, both of these work fine.